# is this php correct for jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am just learning JQM and have had some good guidance from this forum. However, one thing that puzzles me is, do I have to do any special markup to php files. For example, i have a html5 file that collects info via a form and uses ajax to process the form and send to secure php file. for some reason, the login denies or accepts on, but instead of showing secure.php after successful login, it just stays at the html page. This is just a tutorial I am following, but it gives me a chance to study the code in more detail and try to move forward. Can someone please help with this? many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Logistor Login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>


    $(function()
    {
        $("#login_form").submit(function()
        {
             //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading        
            $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
            //check the username exists or not from ajax
            $.post("ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
            {
                if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
                {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
                    {
                          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
                        function()
                        {
                              //redirect to secure page
                              document.location='secure.php';
                        });
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
                     {
                        //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
                        $(this).html('Please provide the correct credentials').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                    });
                }
            });
            return false; //not to post the  form physically
        });
        //now call the ajax also focus move from
        $("#password").blur(function()
        {
            $("#login_form").trigger('submit');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<div data-role="page" id="login" data-title="Logistor Login" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Logistor Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post" id="login_form" action="">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="username">Username *</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="66" />
                <div id="userError">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password">Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="46" />
                <div id="passError">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="login_message"></div>
            <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" /> 
                <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"">
    <h4>Logistor 2009-2011</h4>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

secure.php

```
<?php session_start();


// if session is not set redirect the user
if(empty($_SESSION['u_name']))
    header("Location:index.html");  

//if logout then destroy the session and redirect the user
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.html");
}   

echo "<a href='secure.php?logout'><b>Logout<b></a>";
echo "<div align='center'>You Are inside secured Page</a>";

?>
```

ajax-login.php

```
<?php session_start();


//Connect to database from here
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//select the database | Change the name of database from here
mysql_select_db('test');

//get the posted values
$user_name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name'],ENT_QUOTES);
$pass=md5($_POST['password']);

//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT username_usr, password_usr FROM user_usr WHERE username_usr='".$user_name."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //compare the password
    if(strcmp($row['password_usr'],$pass)==0)
    {
        echo "yes";
        //now set the session from here if needed
        $_SESSION['u_name']=$user_name;
    }
    else
        echo "no";
}
else
    echo "no"; //Invalid Login


?>
```

Comment: You need to show ajax_login.php. It seems like the `u_name` session variable isn't being set.

Comment: @juhana i have updated original code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, you aren't calling that function you're defining in the initial `<script>`. Nothing should work without that.

```
// add () right before the close of the <script>
})();
</script>
```

Comment: That has made no difference apart from it now slides back to index.html. This is where I got the script and it is working on his site as i posted it. http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is year old yet, you should place your siaf(self invoking anonymous function) in the last of your document. These functions start executing before your dom is loaded if it is placed in .

```
<script>
(function(){

})();
</script>
```

may be before the  or at the end of the body.